# Spring constructor dependency Injection Issues

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations, autowired, constructor-injection

I have 2 classes

```
public class Abcd{

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Abcd(@Value("${username}") String userName, @Value("${password}") String password) {
        ...
    }

    public String retrieveValues(){
     ......
     return "someString";
    }

}

public class SomeClass{
    @Autowired
    private Abcd obj;

    public String method1(){
    obj.retrieveValues();
}
```

I have a Xml as below.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:applNew.properties" />

<bean id="abcd" class="com.somecompany.Abcd">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${prop.user}" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${prop.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="someclass"
    class="com.differentcompany.SomeClass">
</bean>
```

When I build the project and start the server, i see the below exceptions.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'abcd' defined in URL []: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class []: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

I dont understand what could be the issue to do a constructor injecting this way. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure Abcd is compiling? The `userName` constructor arg has no type.

Comment: why are you passing `@Value` in constructor of Abcd if you are passing the values through spring (via `${prop.user}`) ?

Comment: @AndreiSfat : I tried not to pass the values then I see another exception similar exception.

Comment: sorry thats a typo error. its String username

Comment: For some reason, you have cglib proxy stuff going on there. Can you post your complete spring config?

Answer (score 3):

Classes to be proxied by CGLIB (for AOP support) must have no-args constructors.

These no-args constructors don't have to be `public` and it doesn't affect anything else - you can use other constructors as usually:

```
public class Abcd{
    // Dummy constructor for AOP
    Abcd() {}

    public Abcd(@Value("${username}") String userName, @Value("${password}") String password) { ... }   
    ...
}
```

**See also:**

- [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

Comment: Why did AOP come into focus when Im no where using it. Im just trying to constructor inject the values.

Comment: @iuser: Perhaps you use a feature that requires AOP: `@Transactional`, `@Async`, `@Cache`, security, etc.